# Depurar não disponível no Visual Studio - debug option not available in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, console-application

When creating a project using the Console Application (.net core) option. the debug option does not work, in its place, only the option "Attach."

image link containing the way it is displayed

In addition, the project is not shown in managing solutions on the right as can be seen in the link in image 2, I don't know if the errors are related.

Solution manager missing project:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the title too.

Comment: @João M, based on your picture, It seems that you only opened program.cs file, please try to open .csproj file to check if you can open the file correctly.